C++/WinRT idiomatic way to dispose of smart pointer class fields
Say I have a basic WinRT class:
// midl
runtimeclass Class: IClosable
{
    Class();
}

// .h
struct Class : ClassT<Class>
{
    Class() = default;
 
    void Close();
    ~Class();

private:
    unique_ptr<Helper> helper = make_unique<Helper>();
};

Now it all works correctly, but when calling my class from C# within a using block (which then calls Dispose, which is translated to Close), the destructor of my class never gets called (maybe when the GC triggers?), which means that my helper never gets destroyed. This is critical for me because that's what flushes the IO streams and closes the files, until then I have 0 byte files sitting around.
As a work-around I made the destructor call Close() (to funnel the code through one function), then made Close() reset the smart pointer to destroy it, but this is so anti-C++. Is there a better, more idiomatic way of doing this that I'm missing?

I think the core issue here is that Class implements IClosable. It is my understanding that this interface is an implementation detail dealt with by the different language projections.

Right, and I'm asking how to deal with it correctly as the component's author

I got that confused with C++/CX where the presence of a destructor is sufficient for the compiler to generate the IClosable interface implementation. In C++/WinRT that doesn't happen. I don't think there's an "idiomatic" pattern; just do what works, e.g., void Close() { helper.reset(); } and keep the default d'tor. The whole RAII idiom falls flat when your types are consumed from language runtimes without deterministic destruction.

Half of me wants to say "so what if the object is technically still alive after a dispose, literally no sane person will use it, so I might as well just delete this; in Close()", but I'm not sure if that will break anything. It's also really weird to do.. I guess I'm hoping there's some hidden way of instructing the cppwinrt compiler to generate this for me, but there probably isn't :(

The destructor will be called when GC happens. Do not delete the object while there are still outstanding references or you will crash when the client calls Release to release the reference.

@RaymondChen yeah I figured. Guess this is the best it gets, thank you all.

It is up to you to decide how much of the object gets cleaned out on Close. And then you have to update all of your methods to deal with the possibility that they are called after close, and return RO_E_CLOSED.
